# Converting String to Date Format

Tags: ios, swift3, nsdateformatter

I'm working with webService, when login process is finished get an authenticate key from server and in other request i'm getting server time there is my JSON structure how can convert this string to date formatter?

```
{
  "ErrorCode": 0,
  "ErrorMessage": "",
  "Result": 0,
  "Long": 1477721881,
  "LongMS": 1477721881610,
  "Net": "/Date(1477721881610+0330)/",
  "Date": "2016.10.29-09:48"
}
```

i want to save this time because authenticate key valid for 24 hour.
there is my code for converting string but my result not correct :

```
  let sysdate = json["Date"] as? String
         let formatter = DateFormatter()
         formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy.mm.dd-hh:mm"
         let dateString = formatter.date(from: sysdate!)
```

this is my result : date format :Optional(2016-01-08 06:59:16 +0000)

Answer (score 1):

- Month is `MM`
- 24 hour format is `HH`

See [Unicode.org: Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)